# How can I list available tags in Magit?

Tags: magit, git

I would like to list the available tags in Magit in order to diff a specific revision, is this possible?

Specifically what I am after is to list the revision history at a certain tag and then view the diff for one of the patches in its history.  I have just completed a rebase and noticed some inconsistencies, I know which patch introduced the change and I would like to see its diff from the version prior to the rebase.

Comment: Not a very robust way, but will work for the lack of better options: `: tag` - `:` will execute `git` with the given argument and `git tag` will just print the list of all tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Specifically what I am after is to list the revision history at a certain tag

It sounds like you already know the tag you need, in which case:

Magit 1.x:
<kbd>l</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> *type tag name (with TAB completion)* <kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

Magit 2.x:
<kbd>l</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> *type tag name (with TAB completion)* <kbd>RET</kbd>

> I have just completed a rebase and noticed some inconsistencies

Or use the reflog to find the pre-rebase hash:

Magit 1.x:
<kbd>l</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>

Magit 2.x:
<kbd>l</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 32):

> I would like to list the available tags in Magit ...

Type <kbd>y</kbd> to show a buffer which lists branches, remote branches, and, at the bottom, tags.

> ...in order to diff a specific revision [reachable from that tag]

Move to the tag and press <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>. That shows the log for that tag. Move to the commit and press <kbd>RET</kbd>. That shows information about that commit, including the diff.

You don't necessarily have to move to the tag first to show the log for it. You can also type <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>`<TAGNAME>`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: The list of tags was too long and distracting for me too see every time I hit `y`, so I configured the `magit-refs-sections-hook` variable to take it out. Is there another way to explicitly list all the tags?

Comment: Instead of removing the tag section you can just configure it to be hidden by default, see `magit-section-initial-visibility-alist`.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work great (I added `remote` and `tags` to that list). Also nice that it remembers the last open/closed state.